# rake assets:precompile of rails 7 application fails on amazon linux 2

Tags: ruby-on-rails-7, amazon-linux-2

I have migrated my Rails application from Rails 6 to 7 and I am successfully able to run it locally. But when I try to deploy this application on AWS - ElasticBeanstalk, it fails during `/bin/su webapp -c bundle exec rake assets:precompile` step.

Below are the deploy logs (`/var/log/eb-engine.log`) from Amazon Linux 2 EC2 instance:

```
[INFO] Starting...
[INFO] Starting EBPlatform-PlatformEngine
[INFO] reading event message file
[INFO] Engine received EB command cfn-hup-exec
[INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c /opt/aws/bin/cfn-get-metadata -s arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:XXXXX:stack/awseb-e-eid-stack/STACK_ID -r AWSEBAutoScalingGroup --region us-east-1
[INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c /opt/aws/bin/cfn-get-metadata -s arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:XXXXX:stack/awseb-e-eid-stack/STACK_ID -r AWSEBBeanstalkMetadata --region us-east-1
[INFO] checking whether command app-deploy is applicable to this instance...
[INFO] this command is applicable to the instance, thus instance should execute command
[INFO] Engine command: (app-deploy)

[INFO] Downloading EB Application...
[INFO] Region: us-east-1
[INFO] envID
[INFO] envBucket: elasticbeanstalk-us-east-1-XXXXX
[INFO] Using manifest file name from command request
[INFO] Manifest name is : manifest_xxxxx
[INFO] Download app version manifest
[INFO] Downloading: bucket: elasticbeanstalk-us-east-1-XXXXX, object: /resources/environments/e-eid/_runtime/versions/manifest_xxxxx
[INFO] Download successful168bytes downloaded
[INFO] Trying to read and parse version manifest...
[INFO] Downloading: bucket: elasticbeanstalk-us-east-1-XXXXX, object: /resources/environments/e-eid/_runtime/_versions/appName/code-pipeline-ID
[INFO] Download successful28982425bytes downloaded
[INFO] Executing instruction: ElectLeader
[INFO] Running leader election for instance i-0d356...
[INFO] Calling the cfn-elect-cmd-leader to elect the command leader.
[INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c /opt/aws/bin/cfn-elect-cmd-leader --stack arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:XXXXX:stack/awseb-e-eid-stack/STACK_ID --command-name ElasticBeanstalkCommand-AWSEBAutoScalingGroup --invocation-id ID --listener-id i-0d356 --region us-east-1
[INFO] Instance is Leader.
[INFO] Executing instruction: stopSqsd
[INFO] This is a web server environment instance, skip stop sqsd daemon ...
[INFO] Executing instruction: PreBuildEbExtension
[INFO] Starting executing the config set Infra-EmbeddedPreBuild.
[INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c /opt/aws/bin/cfn-init -s arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:XXXXX:stack/awseb-e-eid-stack/STACK_ID -r AWSEBAutoScalingGroup --region us-east-1 --configsets Infra-EmbeddedPreBuild
[INFO] Finished executing the config set Infra-EmbeddedPreBuild.
[INFO] Executing instruction: StageApplication
[INFO] extracting /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deployment/app_source_bundle to /var/app/staging/
[INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c /usr/bin/unzip -q -o /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deployment/app_source_bundle -d /var/app/staging/
[INFO] finished extracting /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deployment/app_source_bundle to /var/app/staging/ successfully
[INFO] Executing instruction: RunAppDeployPreBuildHooks
[INFO] Executing platform hooks in .platform/hooks/prebuild/
[INFO] Following scripts will be executed in order: [01_install_packages.sh 02_prepare_bundle_local.sh 03_ebenv.sh 04_install_wkhtmltopdf_kit.sh]
[INFO] Running script: .platform/hooks/prebuild/01_install_packages.sh
[INFO] Running script: .platform/hooks/prebuild/02_prepare_bundle_local.sh
[INFO] Running script: .platform/hooks/prebuild/03_ebenv.sh
[INFO] Running script: .platform/hooks/prebuild/04_install_wkhtmltopdf_kit.sh
[INFO] Finished running scripts in /var/app/staging/.platform/hooks/prebuild
[INFO] Executing instruction: stage ruby application
[INFO] stage ruby application ....
[INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c rbenv global
[INFO] 2.7.5
[INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c bundle --version
[INFO] Bundler version 2.3.10
[INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c bundle config set --local deployment true
[INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c bundle _2.3.10_ install --local

[INFO] Installing rake 13.0.6
Installing concurrent-ruby 1.1.10
Installing minitest 5.15.0
Installing builder 3.2.4
Installing erubi 1.10.0
Installing mini_portile2 2.8.0
Installing racc 1.6.0 with native extensions
Installing crass 1.0.6
Installing rack 2.2.3
Installing nio4r 2.5.8 with native extensions
Installing websocket-extensions 0.1.5
Installing marcel 1.0.2
Installing mini_mime 1.1.2
Installing aws-eventstream 1.2.0
Installing aws-partitions 1.587.0
Installing jmespath 1.6.1
Using bundler 2.3.10
Installing method_source 1.0.0
Installing thor 1.2.1
Installing zeitwerk 2.5.4
Installing jsonapi-renderer 0.2.2
Installing public_suffix 4.0.7
Installing amazon_pay 2.6.1
Installing execjs 2.8.1
Installing faraday-em_http 1.0.0
Installing faraday-em_synchrony 1.0.0
Installing faraday-excon 1.1.0
Installing faraday-httpclient 1.0.1
Installing multipart-post 2.1.1
Installing faraday-net_http 1.0.1
Installing faraday-net_http_persistent 1.2.0
Installing faraday-patron 1.0.0
Installing faraday-rack 1.0.0
Installing faraday-retry 1.0.3
Installing ruby2_keywords 0.0.5
Installing multi_json 1.15.0
Installing bcrypt 3.1.18 with native extensions
Installing msgpack 1.5.1 with native extensions
Installing bootstrap-filestyle-rails 1.2.1
Installing ffi 1.15.5 with native extensions
Installing rexml 3.2.5
Installing browser 5.3.1
Installing climate_control 0.2.0
Installing coderay 1.1.3
Installing coffee-script-source 1.12.2
Installing country-select 1.2.1
Installing dalli 3.2.1
Installing declarative 0.0.20
Installing orm_adapter 0.5.0
Installing hashie 5.0.0
Installing elasticsearch-rails 7.2.1
Installing excon 0.92.3
Installing flutie 2.2.0
Installing formatador 1.1.0
Installing mime-types-data 3.2022.0105
Installing foundation_emails 2.2.1.0
Installing geocoder 1.8.0
Installing jwt 2.3.0
Installing memoist 0.16.2
Installing os 1.0.1
Installing httpclient 2.8.3
Installing trailblazer-option 0.1.2
Installing uber 0.1.0
Installing retriable 3.1.2
Installing webrick 1.7.0
Installing sexp_processor 4.16.1
Installing temple 0.8.2
Installing tilt 2.0.10
Installing honeybadger 4.12.1
Installing htmlentities 4.3.4
Installing jquery-datetimepicker-rails 2.4.1.0
Installing rb-fsevent 0.11.1
Installing json 2.6.2 with native extensions
Installing kaminari-core 1.2.2
Installing memcachier 0.0.2
Installing newrelic_rpm 8.7.0
Installing pg 1.3.5 with native extensions
Installing puma 3.12.6 with native extensions
Installing rails_serve_static_assets 0.0.5
Installing rails_stdout_logging 0.0.5
Installing rdoc 6.3.3
Installing ruby-ole 1.2.12.2
Installing rubyzip 2.3.2
Installing slack-notifier 2.4.0
Installing turbolinks-source 5.2.0
Installing wkhtmltopdf-binary 0.12.6
Installing sitemap_generator 6.2.1
Installing i18n 1.10.0
Installing tzinfo 2.0.4
Installing rack-test 1.1.0
Installing warden 1.2.9
Installing font_assets 0.1.14
Installing rack-cors 1.1.1
Installing rack-maintenance 2.1.0
Installing sprockets 3.7.2
Installing nokogiri 1.13.6 with native extensions
Installing websocket-driver 0.7.5 with native extensions
Installing mail 2.7.1
Installing aws-sigv4 1.5.0
Installing addressable 2.8.0
Installing autoprefixer-rails 10.4.7.0
Installing uglifier 4.2.0
Installing faraday-multipart 1.0.3
Installing elasticsearch-api 7.17.1
Installing bootsnap 1.4.9 with native extensions
Installing braintree 4.7.0
Installing terrapin 0.6.0
Installing pry 0.14.1
Installing coffee-script 2.4.1
Installing mime-types 3.4.1
Installing representable 3.2.0
Installing ruby_parser 3.19.1
Installing haml 5.2.2
Installing recaptcha 5.10.0
Installing sendgrid 1.2.4
Installing rails_12factor 0.0.3
Installing sdoc 1.1.0
Installing spreadsheet 1.3.0
Installing turbolinks 5.2.1
Installing sassc 2.1.0 with native extensions
Installing get_process_mem 0.2.7
Installing rb-inotify 0.10.1
Installing activesupport 7.0.0
Installing aws-sdk-core 3.131.0
Installing css_parser 1.11.0
Installing faraday 1.10.0
Installing pry-rails 0.3.9
Installing fog-core 2.3.0
Installing ruby2ruby 2.4.4
Installing loofah 2.18.0
Installing inky-rb 1.4.2.0
Installing mimemagic 0.3.10 with native extensions
Installing puma_worker_killer 0.3.1
Installing sass-listen 4.0.0
Installing rails-dom-testing 2.0.3
Installing globalid 1.0.0
Installing activemodel 7.0.0
Installing case_transform 0.2
Installing rack-tracker 1.13.0
Installing view_component 2.55.0
Installing wicked_pdf 2.6.2
Installing aws-sdk-sqs 1.51.1
Installing aws-sdk-kms 1.57.0
Installing premailer 1.16.0
Installing faraday_middleware 1.2.0
Installing elasticsearch-transport 7.17.1
Installing signet 0.16.1
Installing twilio-ruby 5.67.0
Installing fog-json 1.2.0
Installing fog-xml 0.1.4
Installing rails-html-sanitizer 1.4.2
Installing sass 3.7.4
Installing activejob 7.0.0
Installing activerecord 7.0.0
Installing paperclip 6.0.0
Installing aws-sdk-s3 1.114.0
Installing avatax 22.3.0
Installing elasticsearch 7.17.1
Installing googleauth 1.1.3
Installing fog-aws 3.14.0
Installing actionview 7.0.0
Installing audited 5.0.2
Installing friendly_id 5.4.2
Installing hairtrigger 0.2.25
Installing kaminari-activerecord 1.2.2
Installing pg_search 2.3.6
Installing pghero 2.8.3
Installing paperclip-compression 2.0.0
Installing elasticsearch-model 7.2.1
Installing google-apis-core 0.5.0
Installing actionpack 7.0.0
Installing jbuilder 2.11.5
Installing kaminari-actionview 1.2.2
Installing elasticsearch-persistence 7.2.1
Installing google-apis-analyticsreporting_v4 0.7.0
Installing actioncable 7.0.0
Installing activestorage 7.0.0
Installing actionmailer 7.0.0
Installing actionpack-action_caching 1.2.2
Installing railties 7.0.0
Installing active_model_serializers 0.10.13
Installing apipie-rails 0.7.2
Installing sprockets-rails 3.4.2
Installing simple_form 5.1.0
Installing kaminari 1.2.2
Installing actionmailbox 7.0.0
Installing actiontext 7.0.0
Installing premailer-rails 1.11.1
Installing coffee-rails 5.0.0
Installing responders 3.0.1
Installing jquery-rails 4.4.0
Installing jquery-fileupload-rails 0.4.7
Installing jquery-ui-rails 5.0.3
Installing masonry-rails 0.2.4
Installing rails-healthcheck 1.4.0
Installing sass-rails 5.1.0
Installing rails 7.0.0
Installing devise 4.8.1
Installing jhtmlarea 0.1.0
Installing active_elastic_job 3.2.0
Installing chartjs-ror 3.7.0
Installing dropzonejs-rails 0.8.5
Installing gridhook 0.2.0
Using s3_direct_upload 0.1.7 from https://github.com/waynehoover/s3_direct_upload.git (at /var/app/staging/vendor/cache/s3_direct_upload-6f6decc75fdf@6f6decc)
Installing bootstrap-sass 3.4.1
Bundle complete! 94 Gemfile dependencies, 205 gems now installed.
Gems in the groups 'test' and 'development' were not installed.
Bundled gems are installed into `./vendor/bundle`

[INFO] Don't run Bundler as root. Bundler can ask for sudo if it is needed, and
installing your bundle as root will break this application for all non-root
users on this machine.

[INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c rbenv rehash
[INFO] encountered a Gemfile.lock, setting proper permissions to user webapp
[INFO] Executing instruction: check default web server
[INFO] Executing instruction: check procfile
[INFO] detected Procfile in application source bundle ...
[INFO] Executing instruction: configure X-Ray
[INFO] X-Ray is not enabled.
[INFO] Executing instruction: Configure proxy Nginx
[INFO] configuring proxy...
[INFO] Copying file nginx/webapp.conf to /nginx/conf.d/elasticbeanstalk/webapp.conf
[INFO] Copying file /opt/elasticbeanstalk/config/private/nginx/elasticbeanstalk-nginx-ruby-upstream.conf to /var/proxy/staging/nginx/conf.d/elasticbeanstalk-nginx-ruby-upstream.conf
[INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c cp -rp /var/app/staging/.platform/nginx/. /var/proxy/staging/nginx
[INFO] Executing instruction: configure healthd specific proxy conf
[INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl show -p PartOf healthd.service
[WARN] Warning: process healthd is already registered...
Deregistering the process ...
[INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl show -p PartOf healthd.service
[INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl is-active healthd.service
[INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl show -p PartOf healthd.service
[INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl stop healthd.service
[INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl disable healthd.service
[INFO] Removed symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/healthd.service.

[INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl daemon-reload
[INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl reset-failed
[INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl daemon-reload
[INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl reset-failed
[INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl is-enabled aws-eb.target
[INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl enable aws-eb.target
[INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl start aws-eb.target
[INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl enable healthd.service
[INFO] Created symlink from /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/healthd.service to /etc/systemd/system/healthd.service.

[INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl show -p PartOf healthd.service
[INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl is-active healthd.service
[INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c systemctl start healthd.service
[INFO] Copying file /opt/elasticbeanstalk/config/private/healthd/healthd_logformat.conf to /var/proxy/staging/nginx/conf.d/healthd_logformat.conf
[INFO] Copying file /opt/elasticbeanstalk/config/private/healthd/healthd_nginx.conf to /var/proxy/staging/nginx/conf.d/elasticbeanstalk/healthd.conf
[INFO] Executing instruction: rake tasks
[INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c npm bin --global
[INFO] /opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/node-install/node-v16.14.2-linux-x64/bin

[INFO] (not in PATH env variable)

[INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c rbenv global
[INFO] 2.7.5

[INFO] Running command /bin/su webapp -c bundle exec /opt/elasticbeanstalk/config/private/checkforraketask.rb assets:precompile
[INFO] Found assets:precompile task in Rakefile
[INFO] Running command /bin/su webapp -c bundle exec rake assets:precompile
[INFO] You don't have dalli installed in your application. Please add it to your Gemfile and run bundle install
rake aborted!
LoadError: cannot load such file -- connection_pool
/var/app/staging/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.9/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
/var/app/staging/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.9/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/var/app/staging/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.9/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:89:in `register'
/var/app/staging/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.9/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/var/app/staging/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.9/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:44:in `require'
/var/app/staging/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.5.4/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:35:in `require'
/var/app/staging/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/dalli-3.2.1/lib/rack/session/dalli.rb:5:in `<main>'
/var/app/staging/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.9/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
/var/app/staging/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.9/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/var/app/staging/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.9/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
/var/app/staging/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.9/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/var/app/staging/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.9/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
/var/app/staging/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.5.4/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:35:in `require'
/var/app/staging/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/actionpack-7.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/mem_cache_store.rb:5:in `<main>'
/var/app/staging/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.9/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
/var/app/staging/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.9/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/var/app/staging/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.9/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
/var/app/staging/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.9/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/var/app/staging/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.9/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
/var/app/staging/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.5.4/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:35:in `require'
/var/app/staging/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-7.0.0/lib/rails/application/configuration.rb:381:in `const_get'
/var/app/staging/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-7.0.0/lib/rails/application/configuration.rb:381:in `session_store'
/var/app/staging/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-7.0.0/lib/rails/application/default_middleware_stack.rb:66:in `block in build_stack'
/var/app/staging/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/actionpack-7.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:72:in `initialize'
/var/app/staging/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-7.0.0/lib/rails/application/default_middleware_stack.rb:15:in `new'
/var/app/staging/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-7.0.0/lib/rails/application/default_middleware_stack.rb:15:in `build_stack'
/var/app/staging/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-7.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:568:in `default_middleware_stack'
/var/app/staging/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-7.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:514:in `block in app'
/var/app/staging/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-7.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:512:in `synchronize'
/var/app/staging/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-7.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:512:in `app'
/var/app/staging/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-7.0.0/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:57:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
/var/app/staging/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-7.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec'
/var/app/staging/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-7.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `run'
/var/app/staging/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-7.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in `block in run_initializers'
/var/app/staging/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-7.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in `run_initializers'
/var/app/staging/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-7.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:369:in `initialize!'
/var/app/staging/config/environment.rb:5:in `<main>'
/var/app/staging/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.9/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
/var/app/staging/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.9/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/var/app/staging/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.9/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
/var/app/staging/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.9/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/var/app/staging/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.9/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
/var/app/staging/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.5.4/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:35:in `require'
/var/app/staging/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-7.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:345:in `require_environment!'
/var/app/staging/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-7.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:507:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
/var/app/staging/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.4.2/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:61:in `block (2 levels) in define'
/var/app/staging/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/opt/elasticbeanstalk/.rbenv/versions/2.7.5/bin/bundle:25:in `load'
/opt/elasticbeanstalk/.rbenv/versions/2.7.5/bin/bundle:25:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)

[ERROR] An error occurred during execution of command [app-deploy] - [rake tasks]. Stop running the command. Error: running rake task assets:precompile failed with error command bundle exec rake assets:precompile failed with error Command /bin/su webapp -c bundle exec rake assets:precompile failed with error exit status 1. Stderr:You don't have dalli installed in your application. Please add it to your Gemfile and run bundle install
rake aborted!
LoadError: cannot load such file -- connection_pool
/var/app/staging/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.9/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
/var/app/staging/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.9/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/var/app/staging/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.9/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:89:in `register'
/var/app/staging/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.9/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/var/app/staging/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.9/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:44:in `require'
/var/app/staging/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.5.4/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:35:in `require'
/var/app/staging/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/dalli-3.2.1/lib/rack/session/dalli.rb:5:in `<main>'
/var/app/staging/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.9/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
/var/app/staging/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.9/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/var/app/staging/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.9/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
/var/app/staging/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.9/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/var/app/staging/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.9/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
/var/app/staging/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.5.4/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:35:in `require'
/var/app/staging/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/actionpack-7.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/mem_cache_store.rb:5:in `<main>'
/var/app/staging/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.9/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
/var/app/staging/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.9/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/var/app/staging/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.9/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
/var/app/staging/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.9/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/var/app/staging/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.9/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
/var/app/staging/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.5.4/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:35:in `require'
/var/app/staging/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-7.0.0/lib/rails/application/configuration.rb:381:in `const_get'
/var/app/staging/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-7.0.0/lib/rails/application/configuration.rb:381:in `session_store'
/var/app/staging/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-7.0.0/lib/rails/application/default_middleware_stack.rb:66:in `block in build_stack'
/var/app/staging/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/actionpack-7.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:72:in `initialize'
/var/app/staging/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-7.0.0/lib/rails/application/default_middleware_stack.rb:15:in `new'
/var/app/staging/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-7.0.0/lib/rails/application/default_middleware_stack.rb:15:in `build_stack'
/var/app/staging/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-7.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:568:in `default_middleware_stack'
/var/app/staging/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-7.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:514:in `block in app'
/var/app/staging/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-7.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:512:in `synchronize'
/var/app/staging/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-7.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:512:in `app'
/var/app/staging/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-7.0.0/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:57:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
/var/app/staging/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-7.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec'
/var/app/staging/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-7.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `run'
/var/app/staging/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-7.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in `block in run_initializers'
/var/app/staging/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-7.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in `run_initializers'
/var/app/staging/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-7.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:369:in `initialize!'
/var/app/staging/config/environment.rb:5:in `<main>'
/var/app/staging/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.9/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
/var/app/staging/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.9/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/var/app/staging/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.9/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
/var/app/staging/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.9/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/var/app/staging/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.9/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
/var/app/staging/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.5.4/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:35:in `require'
/var/app/staging/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-7.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:345:in `require_environment!'
/var/app/staging/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-7.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:507:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
/var/app/staging/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.4.2/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:61:in `block (2 levels) in define'
/var/app/staging/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/opt/elasticbeanstalk/.rbenv/versions/2.7.5/bin/bundle:25:in `load'
/opt/elasticbeanstalk/.rbenv/versions/2.7.5/bin/bundle:25:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
 

[INFO] Executing cleanup logic
[INFO] CommandService Response: {"status":"FAILURE","api_version":"1.0","results":[{"status":"FAILURE","msg":"Engine execution has encountered an error.","returncode":1,"events":[{"msg":"Instance deployment failed. For details, see 'eb-engine.log'.","timestamp":1653470206490,"severity":"ERROR"}]}]}

[INFO] Platform Engine finished execution on command: app-deploy
```

Answer (score 1):

`Dalli` from version 3.0.0 and above has dependency on `connection_pool` gem and interestingly this gem was not downloaded during `bundle install`. Downgrading `dalli` to 2.7.11 resolved this for me.